# Write data from file to database with updating old data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a file with 500-5000 lines which I want to save to my database.
The difficulty here is, that I need to update old data, too - not only inserting.

So I tried different approaches:

- Line per line using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (Very slow but fits my needs)
- Writing 100 lines together using a simple array-buffer (Fast but overwrites, too - or fails duo to duplicate key)
- `LOAD DATA INFILE` (Very fast but overwrites/ignores everything)

I had trouble writing 500 Lines into the database using the first method. The whole process needed ~25-30sec which is way to long. The both other methods are fast (only 1-2sec) but overwrites the old data which I need to update.

The update contains simple incrementing of a counter and inserting a new timestamp.
So the query of the first approach looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `latest`
    ( `hash`,`first_try`,`last_try`, `count_tries`, `sender` )
VALUES
    ( :hash, :first, :last, 1, :sender )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `count_tries` = `count_tries` + 1,
    `last_try` = :last2
```

I didnt know a possibility to do that with 100 inserts, too (which i tried in my seccond approach).

**Do You know any possibility to speed up this line-per-line-query or using `ON DUBLICATE KEY` with multiple inserts, too?**

Any other method with the same result is ofc fine, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the file into a temporary table with the same schema as the original table. Then do:

```
INSERT INTO latest ( `hash`,`first_try`,`last_try`, `count_tries`, `sender` )
SELECT `hash`,`first_try`,`last_try`, `count_tries`, `sender` FROM temp_latest
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    count_tries = count_tries + 1,
    last_try = VALUES(last_try)
```

In an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, `VALUES(col)` contains the value that would be stored in that column if it hadn't been a duplicate.

Comment: Thats genius. I will try that immediately and look how it works!

Comment: Aaaand here comes the first question: I need to know how I can replace the ':last2' with the value of the `last-try`-col of the selected row

Comment: Updated the answer with that, but couldn't you find that in the MySQL documentation?

Comment: To find something you have to know what are you looking for. I never would think of using a function here. My first suggestion was to use `last_try AS something` and using this: `last_try = something`. Thank you for helping out anyway!

Comment: I mean you would just read through the documentation of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it explains it right there.

Comment: I guess I wasnt explicitly looking for it when reading the docu ( I build this query a few days ago when I didnt need it^^). Anyway: It's working! (MySQL complains about doubled col-names but you can get rid of it by using the `table.col`-syntax). Thank you for your fast and great help!